# How to get the indices of a capturing group in a regular expression in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, regex

Given the JavaScript following code

```
var pattern = /abc(d)e/;
var somestring = 'abcde';
var index = somestring.match(pattern);
```

I would like to know the start index of a group match, just like Java's [Matcher.start()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#start(int)) method.

Comment: anything wrong with using [string.indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the offset of some capture group by capturing everything else before that capture group:

```
var pattern = /(^.*abc)(d)e/;
var somestring = 'abcde';
var match = somestring.match(pattern);
var index = match[1].length; // this is the offset of `d` in the string
```

Or, without capturing the start of the subject string:

```
var pattern = /(abc)(d)e/;
var somestring = 'abcde';
var match = somestring.match(pattern);
var index = match[1].length + match.index; // this is the offset of `d` in the string
```

`match.index` is the start index of the match in the string.

Comment: Or simply `3 +  match.index`, given the pattern has a constant size :-)